# cant open image in android studio (file not found)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, assets, resteasy

I'm using android studio and I have some pics located here: `..\app\src\main\res\pics`

I have this method to open images in the adapter java class

```
private Drawable drawImage(String iconString) {
    Log.i(TAG , "icon string = " + iconString) ;
    AssetManager assetManager=ctx.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream;

    try {
        inputStream=assetManager.open("pics/"+iconString+".png");
        Log.i(TAG , "icon string try = " + iconString) ;
        Drawable drawable=Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        return  drawable ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  null;

}
```

I did invoke the method 
but when I build and run it I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: pics/ic_payments.png
06-08 10:10:44.577 8002-8002/ ... W/System.err:    
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: you can't create your custom folders inside `res` folder. You can use only the reserved folders. `assetManager` works only with `assets` directory, where you **can** place your custom directories.

Comment: method will work if you place images into correct directory (assets directlry). `who should i acopmlish this` - `who` or `how`? This question doesn't make any sense in English.

Comment: ok, you should place images not into `res`, but into `assets`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. Check your assets folder path.

**src->main->assets->pics->test.png**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First create asset folder like this.

[image]

Second create folder pics in asset and copy all into that folder files.

Answer (score 0):

Android code "ic_launcher" replace with your image name

1.Create asset folder and

create pics folder(inside of your asset folder)

paste the image in pics folder

```
ImageView imageview;
```

2.Inside of Oncreate

```
 imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
 imageview.setImageDrawable(drawImage("ic_launcher"));
```

3,Outside of Oncreate

```
private Drawable drawImage(String iconString) {
    Log.i(TAG , "icon string = " + iconString) ;
    AssetManager assetManager=getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream;

    try {
        inputStream=assetManager.open("pics/"+iconString+".png");
        Log.i(TAG , "icon string try = " + iconString) ;
        Drawable drawable=Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        return  drawable ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  null;

}
```